# Invalid parameter error while passing xml path to bitmap

Tags: c#, xml, bitmap

I need to pass xml image path to bitmap. I have a xml file where i hv all the images path used in the application. Below is the code. I get invalid parameter error.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        string file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml");
        xmldoc.Load(file);
        string path = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText;
        Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        }
```

Comment: on which line you get the exception.Did you check what the innerText is returning

Comment: I get this
   Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText);-->cannot dereference expression.The pointer is not valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText);     
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img);     
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage (bm);
```

Comment: Am getting file not found exception. But the path is right. Should i include the xml file name in the path?

Comment: This is my xml file.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <ImagesXml> <Ad> <ImageUrl>~/Images/bravo_bronze.jpg</ImageUrl> <AlternateText>Img1</AlternateText> <ImageUrl1>~/Images/bravo_star.jpg</ImageUrl1> <ImageUrl2>~/Images/bravo_bronze-Copy.jpg</ImageUrl2> <ImageUrl3>~/Images/bravo_star-Copy.jpg</ImageUrl3> </Ad> </ImagesXml>

Comment: images folder is within the solution.And i hv included the full path.

Comment: Place your images folder inside the bin/debug or bin/release folder

Comment: can you debug and tell me what you are getting in xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("ImagesXml/Ad/ImageUrl2").InnerText

Comment: InnerText - ~/Images/bravo_bronze.jpgImg1~/Images/bravo_star.jpg~/Images/bravo_bronze-Copy.jpg~/Images/bravo_star-Copy.jpg~/Images/bravo_bronze - Copy (2).jpg